# How can I implement show() hide() function using jQuery in Codeigniter based on onclick of button in a table?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I need to have it so extra information pops up onclick and is otherwise hidden. I have tried using show() and hide() but I am unsure of what I am doing. Thanks guys, Kieran

### View:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Last name</th><th>First name</th><th>Practice</th><th>County</th><th>Email</th><th></th></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($health_professional as $hp): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $hp['last_name'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $hp['first_name'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $hp['practice'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $hp['county'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $hp['email'] ?></td>


            <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="hp/view/<?php echo $hp['hpid'];?>">Expand</a></td>

            </tr>
            <thead>
        <tr><th>Permission to send info?</th><th>Registered</th><th>Attendance</th><th>Date of last update</th></tr>
    </thead>
            <tr id ="trid">
            <td><?php echo $hp['send_info']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $registration_count; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $attendance_count; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $hp['send_info_last_update']; ?></td>                
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

One problem that you are going to run into is that:

```
<tr id="trid">
```

is not going to be a unique id. Since you have an id associated with each $health_professional you can change it to:

```
<tr id="tr-<?php echo $hp['hpid'];?>" class="hidden">
```

Now that you have unique id's and a generic class, set up your link like so:

```
<td><a class="expand" data="<?php echo $hp['hpid'];?>">Expand</a></td>
```

Now in javascript you can call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.expand').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data');
        $('#tr-' + id).show();
    });
});
```

and in your css:

```
.hidden{display:none;}
```

Here is a hardcoded example (terrible styling aside):

http://jsfiddle.net/4qbFQ/

Answer (score 1):

I can't see where you have provided the code where your button is, but you could simply put:

```
onclick="$('#extra_info_div_id').toggle();"
```

In the code for the button.

Comment: sorry will update. Having one of those days where your head refuses to work. edit: sorry should have said. That code does something completely different I just copy pasted my button into it

Comment: Literally change the div id in the code I provided and put the onclick into your button and that will toggle the show/hide.

Comment: Hi I did that but it just seems to repeat the original bit at the top rather than show the information at the bottom.

Comment: So what problems are you having?

Comment: I am trying to make it so that the bottom table only shows up when I click expand so I edited the button to <td><a class="btn btn-info" onclick="$('#trid').toggle();">Expand</a></td> but it only repeats the top bit rather than showing the bottom bit

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#trid').hide();
        $('#expand').click(function(){
            $('#trid').show();
        });
    });
</script>

...

<td><a class="btn btn-info" id="expand" href="javascript:;">Expand</a></td>
```